# Images not displaying in live website

Tags: magento

I have live the magento version 1.6.1.0. Live website doesn't uploading the Product image and other images. Under Media folder no images are not displaying in website. I have changed the File Permissin to 755 and 644 but still the images are not displaying. Any one identify my problem and Provide solution for this..

Comment: what sort of server using? win, linux?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your server configuration, permission 755 for media/ may not be enough.

If you uploaded Magento with your **FTP user**, this user is the owner of media/.
If your **webserver user** (the user which handles the HTTP requests, e.g. www-data) is not in the same user group, he won't have write access.

- If you make the webserver user the owner of media/, should be enough.
- If you put both users into the same group, permission 775 will suffice.
- If this is not possible, you may change the permission for media/ to 777. Every user will be able to write to the directory. Try to avoid this because of security issues.

You may experience the same problem with the directory var/.

Answer (score 0):

I've also had this issue, where Google Chrome would fail to upload images to my production site. I did as [Matthias](https://stackoverflow.com/users/558524/matthias-zeis) has suggested and ensured the permissions were set correctly...still had no luck.

I tried using Internet Explorer to upload the image and it worked. I suggest trying a different browser.

Magento uses Flash to perform the upload...if a different browser does not work, it might be that you do not have the latest version of the flash plugin? You can view which version you have by visiting [Mozilla's plugin check](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/plugincheck/). This works on all major browsers.

Finally, if none of this works for you, you can try the [No Flash Image Uploader](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/Tobias+Renger/extension/1756/no-flash-uploader) extension...